# Matching wrong pattern in regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to capture just 1 word before the equals sign but what is happening is that it is capturing everything before the equal sign. Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text      = "This is = an equal sign";

    Pattern p  = Pattern.compile(" (.*?)=");
    Matcher matcher  = p.matcher(text);  
    if (matcher.find())
    {
         System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

This is the output that I got:

> Match: This is =

Comment: "*output that I got: `Match: This is =`*" I can't reproduce your problem. For me your code prints `Match:  is =`. Demo: https://ideone.com/ZbWLmU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text      = "This is = an equal sign";

    Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s?=");
    Matcher matcher  = p.matcher(text);  
    if (matcher.find())
    {
         System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
}
```

Output : 
Match: is